# How to implement herumi/mcl library into my Android project?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, cross-compiling

I would like to use [herumi/mcl](https://github.com/herumi/mcl) library in my Android project. I posted a question on Author's forum and he replied with these two solutions:

**1.** https://github.com/herumi/bls-eth-go-binary/ provides a static library for Android, which contains mcl functions. You can use them through gomobile .

**2.** https://github.com/herumi/mcl/tree/master/ffi/java provides JNI of mcl. If you can build libmcljava.so for Android by cross-compile, then you can use mcl such as https://github.com/herumi/mcl/blob/master/ffi/java/MclTest.java.

I think that great solution for me is the **second** Option, but i absolutely dont know how. I am using Android NDK to call C code to my app, but thats all i know.

I am looking for some fresh tutorial or something like step-by-step, what would help me to use this library in my Android project. I am working on Windows OS.

Comment: Did you check the [NDK getting started](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides) site? It has plenty of tutorials and information.

Comment: Author newly provides makefiles used fo ndk-build. So i followed these steps:
1. Install libgmp-dev library

2. git clone git://github.com/herumi/mcl

3. Under android/jni folder run ndk-build

-->  library in .so format is generated for each ABI